# Strategies to maintain contract between mocks and APIs

Tags: javascript, testing

Using a mock instead of hitting a 3rd party API like Postgres or Stripe can often be necessary when writing tests. A problem I've seen is when the API can unknowingly diverges from the data the mocks return. How can I maintain the contract between test data and real APIs? This is a Javascript project.

Comment: Integration tests with the real API? Also, what do you mean by "diverge"? Are your dependencies changing their contracts in backwards-incompatible ways?

Answer (score 1):

Great question, this is a very common problem when working with commercial third parties that we don't have access to.

First, always write your integration tests against the real API when possible.

If this is not feasible, try to get a sample of real data returned by the API and build your mocks based on it.  Get multiple samples that represent different scenarios, make sure cover general and edge cases.

If real data is not available, it's time for you to start thinking. Do your research first, try to see what other similar APIs return. Also, ask yourself the following questions:

- What's the data for?
- Who will be using it?
- How will it be stored/displayed?
- What constraints will I find?
- Data types?

Try to come up with a "valid" data model that you think it will be close to the real one. Again, make sure you cover as many scenarios as you can think of.

Spending time on making your mocks as real as possible is worth the effort, it can save you a lot of time and trouble when your start querying the API.

Hope you find this helpful.