# Mocking APIs: Keeping mock data up to date?

Tags: api, development-environment, devops

I'm setting up a development environment for my application. As such, to run it locally, the API dependencies need to be mocked, to keep it as lightweight as possible.

The problem however is keeping the data that the mocks return up to date. i.e. as the APIs and their data matures, it may return vastly different data to what is being mocked. These APIs are our own so we have access to all its data, but having something like a static JSON file which needs to be updated seems unmanageable, especially at scale. What are some good approaches to this problem?

FWIW: [Strategies to maintain contract between mocks and APIs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305733/strategies-to-maintain-contract-between-mocks-and-apis) came the closest to answering this but couldn't specifically enough, hence asking this.

Comment: Have a look into Pact. Might be useful to you. Essentially your consuming apps' mocks are used to generate contract tests for your APIs. As a result, your APIs can't change unless your consumers expect them to, thus preventing stale mocks. May require some workflow adjustments on your part. https://docs.pact.io/

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping the data up to date" - up to date in relation to - what? Editing an example into the question might help.

Comment: I found pact to be an overly complex solution that didn't fit most of my company's use cases.  Try shared schema declarations instead.  Almost anything that amounts to a shared declaration and shared code between apps, however minimal, will reduce risk of a compatibility illusion (misleading mock).

Answer (score 2):

Having mock data on hand that comes back from the API is a great way to maintain control over a local testing environment. It's not clear from your question exactly what purpose you are using the mocked data for so I'll assume testing. In which case the data itself wouldn't need to be up to date with real API responses.

**The mocked data only needs to be accurate against real data with respect to what is being tested**. Example: d*ata size restrictions, data type, expected format (upper/lower case, special characters, date, time, etc), number ranges*. Certain fields, like dates, can be mocked by returning the contents of a function (say, DateTime.Now-1 for a recent LastUpdatedDate value).

It would also be a good idea to have separate tests on your contract expectations - simple integration tests, 3rd party tool, whatever you like. Should these expectations (example: *employee id will always be 4-6 digits long*) be violated you'll know that it may be time to reevaluate your expectation and possibly update your application code to deal accordingly.

Even though your data may be constantly changing, your application still has basic expectations of what it's receiving API responses.

Comment: Thanks. While it may be used for testing, the main purpose of the mock data is for development purposes. That is, to be able to run the application on a local machine without hitting the live APIs.

Answer (score 0):

One comment suggested pact.  It was a huge waste of time for my company. I found pact to be an overly complex solution that didn't fit most of my company's use cases.

**Instead** the API provider and consumer must share some kind of code.  Simpler is better.

Try shared schema declarations instead.  Almost anything that amounts to a shared declaration and shared code between apps, however minimal, will reduce risk of a compatibility illusion (misleading mock).  But only if both the provider and client check both request and response against the schema declaration.

Even a shared repo of integration tests that both app CICD pipelines use, will help.

No matter how careful we are, any kind of fake will fail to reflect all of what is real.  And that's the point.  But fake responses etc help us to see problems in our code sooner, saving rework.  Pushing tests left is great, but don't forget to push assumptions/mocks/schema right (testing them multiple times)